# I can't mix ECS and k8s slaves

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My top level pipeline directive looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            defaultContainer "mycontainer"
            yaml 'my full podspec'
        }
    }
```

Then later in a stage I want to use ECS like this:

```
stage('my stage') {
    agent { node { label 'my-ecs-cluster'; customWorkspace 'myworkspace'; } }
```

I get this error:

```
Also:   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.amazonecs.ECSSlave cannot be cast to org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesSlave
```

If I put the ecs agent in the toplevel pipeline directive and then switch to k8s slaves in subsequent stages I don't get an error. So this is only an issue one way. Very frustrating. I only have a few stages that need the ecs slave for so having to define that as the default in the pipeline definition is a pain.

The bigger issue too is the if I define the ECS slaves in the pipeline definition they are provisioned every time and I have some cases where I don't want them to be provisioned at all because they aren't needed.

Just to add more info, setting agent any or none I don't think will work either because when I specify the agent in multiple stages they use a different container. I want to be able to set the ECS agent at the top-level pipeline when required because then all the stages will run with the same container and use the same workspace.